# opening a native app from a webapp

Tags: iphone

I was wondering if it's possible to achieve some sort of thing?

I have a web app, and for example - I want it to run facebook native app, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom URL scheme for your app.

See this question [iPhone/iPad URL Custom Scheme to open a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210954/iphone-ipad-url-custom-scheme-to-open-a-file)

Comment: You can find al lot off schemes for iPhone apps here: http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes